# Django: CSRF errors with AJAX calls only under Microsoft Edge

Tags: ajax, django, microsoft-edge

We have a Django/React Single Page Application. I'm seeing 403 errors when trying to make AJAX calls under Microsoft Edge. I'm using the typical `getCookie()` code that's recommended by Django that can be found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#ajax. After making the call, I see this specific error: `{"detail":"CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."}`. This is the first time we're testing with Microsoft Edge. We don't have issues with any other browser including IE11. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check that cookies are enabled on Edge?

Comment: @LouisBarranqueiro Yes, I confirmed that cookies are enabled.

Comment: @mathew Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: @gabn88 I'm not 100% sure, but I believe the fix was to clear cookies. This issue still pops up in testing once in a while, but we haven't had any customers complain about it yet.

Comment: For me the issue was that I have a site on www.mydomain.com and mydomain.com. Both have different CSRF tokens, and it seems to send always the mydomain.com version, while the user is automatically redirected (and thus on) www.mydomain.com... Issue is not completely resolved, but this seems to be it. I also had no customer complaints, so I will stop investigating.

Comment: We have clients reporting issues with this, but I can't seem to reproduce anything. We do have "www.ourdomain.com" redirecting to "ourdomain.com", but that doesn't seem to make a difference. the csrftoken cookie is properly set as "ourdomain.com" no matter how the page is accessed.

I understand this is an old topic, but has anyone found any details to go on? We have the problem in Edge here in '21 still